# UWP store app published but not unavailable for 2 days already

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store-apps, publish

I have published UWP app on windows store 2 days ago, it passed all tests and was published successfully in about an hour. But still it is unavailable on the store. On the developer console it has this kind of status:

[image: UWP store screenshot]

What is wrong? I never had this kind of problem before. Published already 5 apps excluding this...

Comment: Be patient. It takes time.

Comment: @JustinXL yes but it never took more than 1 day. I thought I did something wrong

Comment: It's just slow sometimes. You could try Dev Center Support.

Comment: dont worry sometimes it take 3 or 4 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be patient it usually takes time 
But you can contact support from here [Dev Center Support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support) by chatting or email

Answer (score 1):

You may create a [support ticket](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account so that support can review your specific scenario.

Please select **Application** as your Issue Type and click "Submit an incident" on the page.

Or if the issue persists, you can provide your SR ticket number and Store Id in the comment so that I can report them internally.